# Guardar JTable y TextFields

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Quiero guardar un JTable y la información capturada en los TextFields en mi base de datos, para poder consultarlo o modificarlo mas adelante, pensé en usar un `INSERT INTO` para guardar los registros en una tabla de mi bdd, pero el JTable tiene muchos registros, ¿Hay forma de que en un solo registro se guarde todo el JTable y los textfields correspondientes al archivo?,
[image: Imagen JTable y registros]

Este es mi método para guardar el JTable y los textfields, pero estaba pensando que a cada uno de los campos del JTable se guardan cada uno como un registro diferente, lo que quiero es que el JTable generado con todos sus registros correspondientes, junto con los textfields se guarden en un solo registro y poder consultarlos. Algo así como mostrar la tabla con el id 1 y que muestre la tabla completa junto con los textfields correspondientes.

```
public void guardarJTableBDD(Polizas ps, BancoInfo bancI) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < tablaDestino.getRowCount(); i++) {
               
                
                PreparedStatement pst = Conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO registros_generadosExc(columna1, columna2, columna3) VALUES ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? ");
                pst.setString(1, tablaDestino.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
                pst.setString(2, tablaDestino.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
                pst.setString(3, tablaDestino.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
                pst.setString(4, bancI.getNombreCuenta()); 
                pst.setString(5, bancI.getCuenta());
                pst.setString(6, bancI.getCuentaIVA());
pst.executeUpdate();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
        }

    }
```

O si tienen algun consejo de como guardar correctamente esos datos para que en un futuro los pueda consultar ese registro con sus respectivos textfields y jtable.

Espero a verme explicado bien, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: según entiendo quieres este formato INSERT INTO `registros_generadosExc` (`Column1`, `Column2`,`Column3`) VALUES
(1, a,b),(2,a,c),(3, a,b),(4, b,c),(5, a,b);

Comment: Edite la pregunta amigo, para explicar mejor lo que busco realizar..

Comment: La idea que tienes implica denormalizar la BD, porque las entidades que posiblemente identificaste terminarían en una sola agrupando un poco de datos relacionados entre sí. Es posible, pero tiene consecuencias. Habrá muchos datos duplicados y espúrios, el tamaño de cada registro será mucho mayor; leer y guardar "más fácil" hará menos mantenible tu aplicación. Pero esa es una opinión

Comment: ¿Cual podria ser la forma correcta de guardar el JTable y los textfields de manera que en un futuro pueda el usuario consultar ese registro con su respectivo JTable y textfields? Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: como menciona @Alfabravo la normalización de la BD es la afectada, normalmente este tipo de información es guardada con el formato master/detail  que en teoría así deberías aplicar la consulta.  he guardado datos similares a este como master/detail ejemplo Entidad Orden, Entidad Ordendetail  en donde el IdOrden es la relacion entre ambas entidades.  pero no se guarda explicitamente los datos completos si no unicamente las relaciones de las demas tablas que intervienen. y la consulta es la clave para mostrar todo.

Answer (score 0):

Si fuese MVC solo llamas los métodos que tienen los constructores y envías la información completa a la BD, todo depende de como tienes estructurado la BD y el código pero hoy día las Entitys, juegan un papel fundamental y las interfaces ayudan mucho, sin repetir datos ni estructura

Este modelo con el boton inserto dos tablas y me guarda toda la informacion que necesito.

```
private void btnagregardetalleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        agregardeta();
        consultadoc("SELECT * FROM Docu_con WHERE Id_cab = " + jTId.getText() + " ORDER BY Id");
    }
```

y el `agregardeta()` puedo hacer y deshacer con el.

[Modelo Master Detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRQbj.png)